# with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, sql, connector

I've this little code for connect my jsp to my mysql db.

```
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
 Class.forName(driver);

 String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";


 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "test1", "test1");
 Statement cmd = con.createStatement();
 String query = "SELECT * FROM champions";
 ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(query);
 while (res.next()) {
   System.out.print(res.getString("name") + ", ");
   System.out.println(res.getString("title")); 
 }
 res.close(); // chiudere le risorse DB è obbligatorio
 cmd.close();
 con.close();
```

I've added the connector to my build path:

But i'm still get this error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build path is for compilation purpose (assuming you don't have code to include mysql connector jar in package).

If this is web application, add it to lib folder.

If this is standalone application, make sure mysql connector jar available for runtime.

Comment: Hi... this is a web application, and ive added the connector in this way:

right click on project -> properties
-> java build path -> libraries tab -> add library
-> connectivity driver definition -> new driver definition
-> MySQL JDBC Driver -> and ive selected the location of my jar

What is wrong??

I'm still getting the error.

Comment: You need to copy jar to LIB folder of your application.